# Segmentation fault caused by function returning pointer c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This function is very messy and it causes segmentation faults on my tester, is there any way to improve it? it's supposed to take the sku argument which is a property of Product objects and match it to the elements in the inventory array (which consists of pointers to Product and has a size of 50) if found I'm supposed to return the pointer.

```
Product* Supplier::getProduct(const string &sku)
{
bool found = false;
int counter =0;
Product* ret= new Product();

        while (found =false && counter< inventory.size())
        {
                if(inventory[counter] && sku == inventory[counter]->getSKU())
                {
                        found = true;
                        ret = inventory[counter];
                }
        counter++;
        }

        if (found ==false)
        {
                cout << "not found" << endl;

        }
return ret;

}
```

Comment: while (found =false ..) should be while (found == false ...)

Comment: You're leaking memory. You create an instance of `Product` but it's never deleted when an item is found in the inventory.

Comment: Why not get rid of `found` altogether, and return the result as soon as you've found it? And get rid of that `new`; it's causing memory leaks. Return `nullptr`, or throw an exception, if it's not found.

Comment: thank you! I was wondering if it was possible to just return nullptr.

Answer (score 4):

You have the code `found = false`. This needs to be `found == false` or `!found`.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
    while (found =false && counter< inventory.size())
```

to

```
    while (found==false && counter< inventory.size())
```